# How do you get owlapi projects to compile and run on MacOS 12 (which runs Java 19 by default) with Maven?

Tags: java, maven, guice, owl, ontology

Since upgrading to MacOS 12, when I run owlapi-dependent projects that are compiled with Maven, the Guice library which owlapi depends on, throws several different types of exceptions at start time. What can I do to resolve this?

For example:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.getClassLoader(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;

com.google.inject.internal.MessageProcessor visit
INFO: An exception was caught and reported. Message: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyFactoryImpl.<init>()

com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) An exception was caught and reported. Message: Injection failed for interface OWLOntologyFactory
  at [unknown source]

1 error

======================
Full classname legend:
======================
OWLOntologyFactory: "org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyFactory"
========================
End of classname legend:
========================

    at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:576)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:163)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:110)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:87)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:69)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:59)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager.<clinit>(OWLManager.java:42)
    ... 2 more
```

Here are the dependencies in the pom file I'm using:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfact</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.6.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>owlapi-rio</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>owlapi-distribution</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.securityvision</groupId>
            <artifactId>xattrj</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: is there a reason for importing `guice` in your POM file? I also doubt that the GUICE version is aligned with the OWL API version and latest OWL API version is 5.1.20 which is 5 years newer than 5.1.0. In addition, technically OWL API 5.1.X is still on Java 8, with 5.5.0 (still SNAPSHOT only) it will officially support Java 11. Did you try with an older Java version?

Comment: I suggest 1) omit guice depdendency 2) update owlapi version to 5.1.20 and if this all doesn't help to 3) try with Java 11 or something

Comment: Based on the subject that you are trying to run on JDK19 I strongly recommed to use most recent versions of all dependencies for example: (https://search.maven.org/artifact/net.sourceforge.owlapi/owlapi-distribution)

Comment: Yeah as uninformeduser says, guice version numbers don't match owlapi and that dependency shouldn't be there

Answer (score 1):

Thr guice dependency was removed from the 5.x branch of owlapi a few years ago. Try updating owlapi to 5.1.20 and removing the explicit guice dependency in your pom. This should exclude all guice references. If necessary, exclude it from the jfact dependency as well (I have not tried jfact with any java version past 8 but i would expect it to work, it doesn't have any features that are known to be incompatible with newer jdks.